# How to get all objects of a specific type in a list?

Tags: java, design-patterns, instanceof

If I have a list of fruits, containing all sort of `Fruit` implementations like `Apple`, `Banana`, etc. The list is necessary as other methods perform general actions on all fruits in the list.

How can I get all objects of a specific type out of the list? Eg all apples? Doing instanceof/if-else checks is very ugly, especially when there are lots of classes to differ.

How can the following be improved?

```
class Fruit;
class Apple extends Fruit;
class Banana extends Fruit;

class FruitStore {
    private List<Fruit> fruits;

    public List<Apple> getApples() {
        List<Apple> apples = new ArrayList<Apple>();

        for (Fruit fruit : fruits) {
            if (fruit instanceof Apple) {
                apples.add((Apple) fruit);
            }
        }

        return apples;
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't `instanceof` the obvious way how tell objects by type? It works, use it.

Comment: Alternatively, use the visitor pattern or some other application of polymorphism to avoid having to filter the list in the first place.

Comment: Alternatively you could use `HashMap` with key as the `fruit Type name` and value as the `ArrayList` of objects of that `fruit`

Comment: Yes instanceof works, but this is just an example at gets messy on more complicated cases.

Comment: @membersound - could you explain why you need such a method? maybe its possible to design around the need for this

Comment: A `Canvas` containing lots of class `Shape` implementation. Every now and then I need just a particular class of the shapes list. But I must still have the shapes list for eg. quick drawing all objects onto the canvas. But I think this is very similar to the example I brought above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know - instance of is bad practice of code.

What about writing .getType(), returned enum type of object?

Comment: that's probably better than doing all the getclass, instanceof stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You make the method generic:

```
public <T extends Fruit> List<T> getFruitsByType(Class<T> fType) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (Fruit fruit : fruits) {
        if (fruit.getClass() ==  fType) {
            list.add(fType.cast(fruit));
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

And use it as follows:

```
FruitStore fs = new FruitStore();
List<Apple> apples = fs.getFruitsByType(Apple.class);
```